# Ant Design Upload component rescales images to 200x200 [React]

Tags: reactjs, antd

I met an issue at Ant Design `<Upload />` component. When I upload an image it sends two Img typed requests at [the Network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6fPl.png). First contains my orginal image (tested at 650x650 image size), second contains transformed image to 200x200. And here is my question: Why image is rescaled to lower resolution and how can I prevent that? I want to upload orignal images with transparency if that is required.

In my case `Upload` component is used to upload single image. Component is placed on modal component that is why I prepared `dummyRequest`.

```
const UploadImage = ({
  defaultValue,
  maxFilesAmount,
}: IUploadImageProps<any>): JSX.Element => {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<IUploadFile<any>[]>(
    defaultValue ?? []
  )

  const onChange = useCallback(
    (info: IUploadChangeParam<IUploadFile<unknown>>): void => {
      setFileList(info.fileList)
    },
    [setFileList]
  )

  const onPreview = useCallback(async (file: IUploadFile): Promise<void> => {
    let src: string | undefined = file?.url ?? file?.thumbUrl ?? ''

    if (!_.isNull(src)) {
      src = await convertImportImageToBase64(src)
    }

    const image: HTMLImageElement = new Image()
    const imgWindow: Window | null = window.open(src)

    image.src = src
    imgWindow?.document.write(image.outerHTML)
  }, [])

  const dummyRequest = useCallback(({ onSuccess }: IUploadRequestOption) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      //@ts-ignore
      onSuccess('ok')
    }, 0)
  }, [])

  const beforeUpload = useCallback((): false => {
    //Required to ignore Ant Desing default converting uploaded image
    //For example that removes transparency from png files
    return false
  }, [])

  return (
    <Upload
      accept={'.jpg, .jpeg, .png'}
      listType={'picture-card'}
      beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
      fileList={fileList}
      onChange={onChange}
      onPreview={onPreview}
      customRequest={dummyRequest}
    >
      {_.size(fileList) < (maxFilesAmount ?? 1) && 'Upload'}
    </Upload>
  )
}
```

At the start I had also a problem with losing transparency at .png images. Image still was defined as png but transparent background got a white color. Used `beforeUpload` fix that, I not sure why but okej :).

What can I do more to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for desicion, like i did: you need to add `previewFile` prop, that will return desirable url string

```
const getBase64 = (file: RcFile): Promise<string | ArrayBuffer> =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        });

    <Upload
        beforeUpload={() => false}
        listType="picture-card"
        multiple={true}
        fileList={fileList}
        previewFile={getBase64 as any}
        onPreview={handlePreview}
        onChange={handleChange}
    >
            {fileList.length >= 3 ? null : uploadButton}
    </Upload>
```